# Return Anonymous Type using SqlQuery RAW Query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, entity-framework

How can I make Entity Framework SqlQuery to return an Anonymous type.

Right now I run a `context.TheObject.SqlQuery()` RAW query. the query joins two tables and I want to return the results of the joined tables.

If I use it with a type `context.TheObject.SqlQuery()` I only get to see the results of the table of that same type.

I tried `db.Database.SqlQuery<DbResults>("the sql query here")`; With a pre-defined class that matches the result's objects, but all the fields are null.

Using Entity Framework 6 with MySQL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb here, and will try to address your underlying problem instead of directly answering your question.

Your scenario with the pre-defined class *should work*. A likely pitfall is that the column names and the properties of your class did not match up.

Sample code (LinqPad)

```
    var results = Database.SqlQuery<TestResult>("select r.Name, b.BankName from relation r inner join BankAccount b on b.RelationId = r.Id where r.Id = 2");
    results.Dump();
}

public class TestResult {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }
```

I'd strongly advise you to revisit your problematic code using explicit types.

---

In direct response to your question: no, you can't return anonymous types from SqlQuery. The best you can do is build *dynamic objects*, but that unfortunately requires a fair bit of manual work using TypeBuilder. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206416/Use-dynamic-type-in-Entity-Framework-SqlQuery for a sample.

Comment: It's important to note that the properties must have getters and setters. This doesn't work: `public class TestResult { public string Name; public string BankName; }`.

Comment: Technically those are fields, not properties... but yes, that's a common pitfall that's probably good to point out.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did.

> 1. Execute sp and get the results into a data reader

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetAnonymousResults(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, string spName, SqlParameter[] outParameters, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {

            //meh, you only need the context here. I happened to use UnitOfWork pattern and hence this.
            var context = unitOfWork as DbContext;

            DbCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = spName;
            command.Connection = context.Database.Connection;

            command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

            //Forget this if you don't have any out parameters
            command.Parameters.AddRange(outParameters);

            try
            {
                command.Connection.Open();
                var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                return reader.ToObjectList();//A custom method implemented below
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

> 2. Read individual values from each row into a expando object and put the list of expando objects into an array

```
            public static List<object> ToObjectList(this IDataReader dataReader, bool ignoreUnmappedColumns = true)
            {
                var list = new List<object>();
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> columnsName = dataReader.GetColumnNames();//A custom method implemented below 
                    var obj = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;

                    foreach (var columnName in columnsName)
                    {
                        obj.Add(columnName, dataReader[columnName]);
                    }
                    var expando = (ExpandoObject)obj;

                    list.Add(expando);
                }

                return list;
            }
```

> 3. Get the list of columns by using the reader.GetSchemaTable() method

```
           public static IEnumerable<string> GetColumnNames(this IDataReader reader)
                {
                    var schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                    return schemaTable == null
                        ? Enumerable.Empty<string>()
                        : schemaTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(row => row["ColumnName"].ToString());
                }
```

> Usage

```
 var results =
                  await
                      StandaloneFunctions.GetAnonymousResults(_unitOfWork, "spFind",
                          outputParameters,parameters);
```

In my case, I happened to use SPs but this should work with queries. All you have to do is replace the command with the following ( and remove all the parameter passing)

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = "select * from SomeTable";
```

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: But, but, but... This isn't EF.

Comment: Great workaround!! I think with plain EF we can't achieve straight SQL to result without creating classes. In my case I have dynamic quires and I can't anticipant what class the query will be mapping to so this is great solution. Thanks for saving me time. I made a slight change to the return type instead of returning List<objects> we can return List<Dictionary<string, object>> my dictionary values have CSV string which needs to be converted into list.