# Read a non typed result of a stored procedure with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am using Entity Framework for calling a stored procedure.

When I call a stored procedure that returns a result set from a table, it works:

```
var user= context.Database.SqlQuery<User>("get_My_User, @Name, @Mail",
            new SqlParameter("@Name", 'Maurice'),
            new SqlParameter("@Mail", 'maurice.abruti@yahoo.com')
            ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Unfortunately when I call a stored procedure with a result set that is not a table, I cannot get any result.

This attempt always returns -1:

```
var result = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("my_stored_procedure @Param1, @Param2",
 new SqlParameter("@Param1", "value1"),
 new SqlParameter("@Param2", "value2"));
```

This other attempt returns a list of null objects:

```
 var generatedDesignations = context.Database.SqlQuery<Object>(
        "my_stored_procedure @Param1, @Param2",
    new SqlParameter("@Param1", "value1"),
    new SqlParameter("@Param2", "value2")).ToList();
```

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: When you're talking of 'result that comes from multiple table', do you mean a stored procedure returning multiple data sets?

Comment: no, I just take columns from different tables

Comment: Why use Entity Framework at all for this?  Seems like a perfect use case for Dapper.

Comment: @DavidL cause in my project , stored procedure return a table's content the post part of the time

Comment: I'd read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852912/return-anonymous-type-using-sqlquery-raw-query-in-entity-framework/29854997#29854997) to a similar question (not tested it myself). It's potentially going to get somewhat complicated and in your place I'd be asking myself if the benefits are worth the complication, rather than just refactoring to use appropriate types. It might well be in your situation, but I'd look at how I was going to work with the data once I got it.

Comment: @Tone you are right , thank you

Comment: I have seen this time and again and the culprit *most likely* is that you did did not execute `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your stored procedure so the table (SELECT statement) is not being returned to EF as the first result in the result set which is why you have `NULL` being materialized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting data from stored procedure with Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140774/getting-data-from-stored-procedure-with-entity-framework)

Comment: @VivienPipo Check duplicate question. It returns -1 like yours and probably the duplicate answer will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I do not konow use of SqlQuery and ExecuteSqlComman methods.Bu i can recomment another way.
If you define the Stored Procedure in the VS's Server Explorer,its usage is easier.You can use it as a method.In order to define it;
1) open Server Explorer,
2) Find Stored Procedure of Data Connection.
3) Right click and add write the stored procedure.
4) Update it.
5) Update the EDMX
6) Use the Stored procedure context.StoredProcedureName(paramters)