# EntityFramework DbContext and raw sql query returning full result

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a question about SqlQuery method used in entity frameworks db context.

It basically works and looks like for example:

```
connection.Database.SqlQuery<TResult>("SELECT capture_instance as CaptureInstance FROM cdc.change_tables ").ToList();
```

But if I want a full table I need to pass a model of it, else I need to pass string if table returns only one column.

Is it possible for this method to return full table content in some sort of generic collection??

Comment: Are you using SqlQuery deliberately, or are you looking for the 'proper' EF way to read an entire table?  If you want to retrieve the table in EF, you will need to create model classes, see virtually any EF tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: Aye it is used on purpose as I need to get data from cdc tables, that includes executing some function etc, witch entity framework as orm is not fully compatible.

Comment: Using EF for an edge case where you can't rely on an entity declaration you should be able to return a complete set of data simply by declaring a POCO class to contain the appropriate result types and feeding that to the SqlQuery call as the type parameter. I'd be extremely wary of unconditionally returning *all* rows unless you're absolutely sure the table size is within reason. See the response for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852912/return-anonymous-type-using-sqlquery-raw-query-in-entity-framework