# How to get Count from FromSql?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have

```
dbContext.Items.FromSql("SELECT COUNT(*) 
                         FROM Items 
                         WHERE JSON_VALUE(Column, '$.json') = 'abc'")
```

This returns an `IQueryable`, I am wondering how I can return a scalar `int` back?

Comment: Why you want use FromSql, instead of just `db.Items.Count()`:

Comment: After reading marco answer looks like you need SqlQuery Instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005901/entity-framework-code-first-execute-scalar-valued-functions

Comment: He probably is using EF Core. SqlQuery is in EF 6.x

Answer (score 5):

## As of EF Core 3.1, 2020

```
var count = dbContext.Set.FromSqlRaw(/* {raw SQL} */).Count();
```

Will generate the following SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*)::INT
FROM (
    -- {raw SQL}
) AS c
```

where `{raw SQL}` is of the form

```
select count(*) from my_table where my_col_condition = true group by my_col_id
```

The count work can then perfectly be done on the database-side this way, without loading table rows on the client.
**Be careful not to end `{raw SQL}` with `;`.**

Comment: this will always return 1 since your raw sql already performs a count and you add another Count() on top of it, no?

Comment: @RomainHautefeuille No cause the nested `count` ends with `group by my_col_id`

Comment: I'm upvoting because this answer helped me, however I don't see the point of adding a `GROUP BY` and a `COUNT` in the raw SQL query. Just writing a `SELECT *` and performing a `CountAsync()` in C# generates exactly the query I needed. Also, `FromSqlRaw` returns an `IQueryable`, meaning no  data is returned to the client at this point. The SQL query is executed only when we reach the `CountAsync()` instruction.

Answer (score 2):

the fastest hack/workaround is if your Item class has an int/long property (lets say Id) you can treat it like this:

```
   dbContext.Items.FromSql("SELECT COUNT(*) as Id
                     FROM Items 
                     WHERE JSON_VALUE(Column, '$.json') = 'abc'").Select(x=>x.Id).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 var firstElement = dbContext.Items
                             .FromSql (..)
                             .ToList
                             .First();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass *composable* `SELECT` SQL to `FromSql` method, e.g. `SELECT *` - see [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql). Then you can apply regular LINQ `Queryable` operators, including `Count`:

```
var count = dbContext.Items
    .FromSql("select * FROM Items Where JSON_VALUE(Column, '$.json') = 'abc'")
    .Count();
```

Comment: Yea but won't that return all the objects and then count them, not as good as just getting a count back...but reading Marco's post this seems to be the only way.

Comment: No, *composable* means EF Core will create SQL on top of it, e.g. something like  `SELECT Count(*) FROM (your select SQL here)`

Comment: Btw, looking at your recent EF Core related questions, looks like you use `FromSql` just because you need `JSON_VALUE` function. Then you may find this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017204/expression-tree-to-sql-with-ef-core/52018037#52018037 interesting, because it allows you to use regular LINQ query with all its benefits.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:
`dbContext.Items.Count()`

You always can do a `.Count()`Function on an IQueryable

Edit:
When the need of a FromSql is really there something like this should do the job:

```
var count = context.Items.FromSql("Select count(*) from items").First();
```

Comment: Normally that would work, but I actually removed the where clauses to simplify my example and I need to use FromSQl as the where clause is a condition on a column that is JSON and EF Core can't do where clauses with linq on JSON

Comment: Something like this should work:
`var count = context.Items.FromSql("Select count(*) from items").First();`

Comment: That still comes back as an "Item" object and not an int.

Comment: @chobo2 In that case this might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852912/return-anonymous-type-using-sqlquery-raw-query-in-entity-framework

Comment: I will have to try that out, should be find I guess as I just need a int back.

Answer (score -1):

[FromSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) has some limitations:

- The SQL query must return data for all properties of the entity or query type.

So, try this:

```
var elements = dbContext.Items
                         .FromSql("SELECT * from dbo.Items")
                         .ToList();

var countOfElements = elements.Count();
```